# Going From Solution To Equation - Higher Order Linear Differential - General Formula

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, diagonalization

I've been given the full solution

$L_{inhom} = c_1*e^{\lambda_1*t}+c_2*e^{\lambda_2*t}+ x_{01}(t)+x_{02}(t)$

Where $f(x_{0i})=q_i(t)$

I wish to find the coefficients for the original equation.

I know, quite circumstantially, that for higher order linear differential equation with real constants (HLDiff from now on) and degree 2, that

$(\lambda -\lambda _1)*(\lambda -\lambda _2)= \lambda ^2+a_1*\lambda +a_0$

I've found this by setting

$\lambda_1 = (-a_1-sqrt(a_1^2+4*a_0)/2 \wedge \lambda_1 = (-a_1+sqrt(a_1^2+4*a_0)/2$

And then expanding the expression.

I have tried it with other numerical lambdas and full solutions, where $\forall\lambda(\lambda\in\Re\wedge am(\lambda)=1)$, and it seems that the formula

$(\lambda -\lambda _1)*(\lambda -\lambda_2)+...+(\lambda-\lambda_{n})=\lambda^n+a_{n-1}*\lambda^{n-1}+...+a_0$

Works in a general sense.

Problem is, how would I go about proving this?

The solution I use (and therefore the knowledge I have wrt. HLDiffs) is dependent on turning the HLDiff of order n into a 1. Degree systems of linear differentialequations, and from there using the "diagonalization" formula:

$X(t) = c_1*e^{\lambda_1*t}*V_{\lambda_1} + ... + c_n*e^{\lambda_n*t}*V_{\lambda_n}$

With the lambdas found from the matrix that occurs as a result of turning the single equation into a system of equations.

Comment: @Moo Oh I think I get it now... We can continue to factor out the characteristic polynomial using its roots, which will eventually lead to $(\lambda-\lambda_1)*...*(\lambda-\lambda_n)$.

Where the left hand side will be the original characteristic polynomial (containing the original diff-eqs coefficients) and the right hand side the formula I wrote above.

Is this correct?

Comment: @Moo Alright, thank you very much for the help! If you want to, you can post your solution as an answer and I'll accept it. Otherwise, I will just do it myself :)